# Monero RPC over SSL for client and server

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, security, rpc

I am trying to setup an RPC connection between monerod and monero-wallet-cli over SSL. For monerod, the recommended way seems to be to use nginx as a reverse proxy and add SSL support there. How do I use this SSL connection from monero-wallet-cli (and/or the GUI wallet too)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have setup the tunnel, it is equivalent to having monerod running in localhost. It is transparent for monero-wallet-cli and monero-wallet-gui.

The only difference, that i noticed so far, is that it doesn't accurately detect network failures, as the connexion with the tunnel manager stays up.

You can see [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3466/110) an example of setup using stunnel.

Comment: So the answer is that the client DOES NOT support SSL connections but an external program can be used (such as stunnel) that can provide these services.